# Laravel: Eloquent relations suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

After a recent update to my live environment, I got some errors about case sensitive model names that were not found but I fixed those quite fast. Now, after about a week after this update I suddenly receive errors about "property of non object" while trying to access related objects.
Here are my models:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class products extends Model {
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'v_products_2';
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class order extends Model {
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'v_customers_orders';

    public function getProduct (){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\products', 'product_id', 'product_id');
    }   
}
```

I've setup my routes and middlewares correctly and after trying to access a property like this will result in an "non-object" error:

```
echo $orders->getProduct->product_id;
```

However this exact same code worked like 2 hours ago and has been working for several months now. Except that, this code also works on my Windows Homestead environment making it very hard for me to troubleshoot it. The only way I was able to reproduce this error locally, was to remove the getProduct function from the model. But on live, I get the same behaviour either way.

Comment: You might need to do a HasMany relation in the product model... see if that clears it

Comment: Trying to convert the query to hasMany, I noticed that by downloading and importing the whole DB on my local enviroment, helped me reproduce the error. So this is a DB problem. Any idea what the exact cause might be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about databases, not programming. There's a separate SE site for [database questions](dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It isn't solely a DB issue. It is more like what caused the DB issue to begin with so it has to do with the framework. I'm developing this webpage for quite some months now and this has never happened before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that my orders table had some entries of products that were deleted from the products table. The result was that an array was returned instead of an object. Deleting/editing the problematic rows made the code work again as before.

Comment: You rock sir ! thank you for your answer that was really helpful, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change class names, to first letter uppercase, and then relation `App\Products`.

Comment: I've made some progress... I can access the array[key] value but I can't access it as an object. This works: $order->getProduct['carrier'] while this doesnt: $order->getProduct->carrier. Any idea why?

Comment: Try to change method name for example `public function product ()`.

Comment: It keeps returning a serialized string which can be echoed like $order->getSomeProduct

Answer (score 0):

You will get a non-object error when your get_product() function returns a value null. Try to add a condition to check null value before calling the property.

Comment: My getProduct function returns a serialized array instead of an object. Its not null its just not an object. I can access the values with i.ex. $order->getProduct['carrier']  instead of $order->getProduct->carrier. This started happening a day ago. Any idea why?